# Why do we need to keep state trie? Only for the computation speed?

Tags: state-trie

I'm studying solidity these days and came up with this silly question. 
Is there any other reason why every node is maintaining state trie?

Comment: It makes it very cheap to confirm parts of the state, e.g. your address’ balance, without re-running all transactions.